# Tar several files keeping directory tree

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tar

Ive been looking at this for hours, and cant find a way to tar several files with directory structure ( tree )

Example:

I have files in:

```
1. /home/user/somefolder/file.txt
2. /home/user/somefolder/file2.txt
3. /home/user/somefolder/file3.txt
4. /home/user/somefolder/somefolder2/file2.txt
5. /home/user/somefolder/somefolder3/file3.txt
```

now i want to take files 1+4 and tar it.

```
tar cvzf file.tar.gz /home/user/somefolder/file.txt /home/user/somefolder/somefolder/file2.txt
```

but it takes those files and tar it into one file without keeping the second some folder while i want to tar file to look like this:
tarfile

```
somefolder
|-- file.txt
|-- somefolder2
    |-- file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this tar:

```
tar -cvz -f file.tar.gz -C /home/user/somefolder/ file.txt file2.txt file3.txt \
                        -C /home/user/somefolder/somefolder2/ file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: Well , it didnt worked


    tar -cvzf file.tar.gz -C /home/admin/ /home/admin/1.txt \ -C /home/admin/domains/ /home/admin/domains/test.txt
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/home/admin/1.txt
tar:  -C: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
/home/admin/domains/
/home/admin/domains/test.txt
/home/admin/domains/test/
/home/admin/domains/test.txt
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Answer (score 0):

Well, silly me

When using full path from a remote directory tar saves the entire tree of the folders.

so there isnt really any issue :) sorry